# Eclipse Formatting. Remove new line before opening brace for block

Tags: java, eclipse, block, braces

Is there a way to prevent Eclipse from adding a new line before block opening brace ?

Eclipse format following code

```
p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)); {
    p.add(login);
    p.add(password);
}
frame.add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

to

```
p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
{
    p.add(login);
    p.add(password);
}
frame.add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: Why would you do that? The block is an anonymous block, which is not related to the declaration of the Panel at all. Are you sure you don't confuse this with the code for a handler attached to the panel? That would be formatted as you wish.

Comment: I use anonymous block to make easier re-reading. All of this block content will be added to the panel and is indented.

Comment: Cool. I'm also using this technique to hide repetitive local variables and/or decouple some code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use this technique sometimes.

I think you will not be able to do this in Eclipse.

And I would say, this is good :)

Think, `p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));` is not a statement that controls the following block and thus it can not open it. When reading the code when we find `}` we intuitively expect for/if/etc in the start which is synonym to `{`. But there is just `p = new ...` It does not make any sense - the first thought would be, where is IF or something ! :)

We just want the block be separate from the outer block - textually or in vars visibility. So when scrolling up we found the starting `{` at the same indentation (no controlling or other statements before) - and that's it. No other thoughts, all good.

Just change the way you are thinking of it and you will enjoy `{` at the begging of line.

p.s. I use standard formatting so all other starting braces are at the end of line in my code.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I agree with you in this sense.

It is just a convention I always use for this particular case. I will think of it differently...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project->Properties->Java Coe Style->Formatter->Configure Workspace Settings->Edit->Braces

Change "Anonymous class declaration" to "same line"

Comment: All braces positions are defined as "Same Line"

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a big fan of keeping my initialization code grouped in a block within the creation of my classes.  So here's a little trick I use that takes advantage of static initializers:

```
p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)) {{
    add(login);
    add(password);
}};
frame.add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

As you can see, you can make calls to "add" without needing to prefix them with "p." as in: "p.add", and you no longer need to worry about Eclipse putting the braces at the beginning of the next line, since the semicolon is placed at the end of the whole block.